# how to take certain phrases from a regex and place them into different groups in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Below is a string that I have been working with for awhile (example is based on Apple's example for coding and emails):

```
2.3|[jappleseed@example.com][pwd_removed][johnnyappleseed@example.com][Johnny][Appleseed][APPLES]
```

This comes from a database I use that holds accounts. Every person who is registering has to have these, so every line is formatted the same. They will be different information, but still formatted the same. In order to register for an account, you need a username, password(which is invisible to me), an email address and a 6 character code.

What I am trying to do is take the username, email address, First name, Last name, and the 6 character code into different groups. Below is a regex statement I have been working on:

```
^.*\[(.*)\]$
```

The problem with this statement is that it matches everything in the statement, and I want it matched in groups. I understand this is where I need to use Split method, but I have no idea as to how I can use the Split method to place what I want in groups. So my question is: do I have to make multiple lines of code for one group, or is there a method that can make my life a lot easier? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex. Just split on `'['` and `']'`, remove empty entries, and then skip the first part (the `2.3`):

```
string[] parts = input.Split(new[] { '[', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do have one question: If I needed to get the username out as an example, how would I call for it?

Comment: @user4970927 I think that the username is the first field, so it would just be `parts[0]` (remember arrays are 0-based).

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(\[[^\]]+\])
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/hS6mC8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for 6 different capture groups so you're looking at a pattern like:

```
@"^.*\[(?<username>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<password>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<email>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<fname>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<lname>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<charcode>[^\]]+)\]"
```

This is an example of named capture groups which have be accessed like so:

```
string data = "2.3|[jappleseed@example.com][pwd_removed][johnnyappleseed@example.com][Johnny][Appleseed][APPLES]";
string pattern = @"^.*\[(?<username>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<password>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<email>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<fname>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<lname>[^\]]+)\]\[(?<charcode>[^\]]+)\]";
Match match = Regex.Match(data, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["username"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["password"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["email"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["fname"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["lname"]);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["charcode"]);
}
```

Results:

```
jappleseed@example.com
pwd_removed
johnnyappleseed@example.com
Johnny
Appleseed
APPLES
```

Otherwise, removed the names from the capture group and you have a pattern like:

```
@"^.*\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]"
```

Which can be accessed as such:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[4]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[5]);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[6]);
```